# How to validate single field of a model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a model called User and its $validate has 39 field validations and working fine in UsersController. In another controller I need to use the same code and validate only a single field from controller. Can Someonce please help me with this?

Comment: Any code you tried so far? You should really post something here so that it is more concrete and less theoretical.

Comment: @silentboy aparently, the OP doesn't know how to do this. While true that an answer may have easily been found on Google, please make your comments more 'constructive' than 'this is a stupid question'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Relevant docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html).

Use the `fieldList` option in the model's `validates()` method.

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->data);
if ($this->ModelName->validates(array('fieldList' => array('myField')))) {
    // If myField validated successfully...
}
```