# How to validate partially a model in cakephp 3

Tags: php, validation, cakephp-3.0

I want to validate certain field of my model, as I'm implenting multi-step form.
[This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679943/how-to-validate-single-field-of-a-model-in-cakephp) from CakePHP 2 does not work in version 3. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah looks like in cake 3 they got rid of the validates() method. validation is only triggered when you call `newEntity` or `patchEntity`. If it is important to validate one by one you may need to patch each field seperately and check for errors after each one.

```
$userEntity = $usersTable->newEntity();
$userEntity = $usersTable->patchEntity(['email' => 'not an email!!']);
if($userEntity->errors('email')){
    return false; // Invalid email
}
```

as per

> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-validation-as-application-rules

Comment: How about multiple fields ? I proceed like this `if($userEntity->errors(['email', 'username']))` but still get message about all other fields.

Comment: hmm interesting. maybe try [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#validating-data). `$errors = $validator->errors($this->request->data());
if (isset($errors['email'])) {
    return false;
}`

Answer (score 4):

See the documentation on [using a different validation set](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-a-different-validation-set). You will need to set up functions for validating each step of the form, and specify which function to use in your `newEntity` or `patchEntity` call. For a multi-step form, the validation for the second step would presumably add the validation for the first step, to ensure that no tampering was done with the data in between. So, you'd have something like this:

In the controller function for step1:

```
$entity = $table->newEntity(
    $this->request->data,
    ['validate' => 'step1']
);
```

and in the controller function for step2:

```
$entity = $table->newEntity(
    $this->request->data,
    ['validate' => 'step2']
);
```

etc.

In your table class:

```
public function validationStep1($validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('email', 'notEmpty', [
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => __('Provide a valid email'),
        ])
        ->add('username', 'notEmpty', [
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => __('Provide a valid username')
        ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

(presumably with other validation, like ensuring that the email address makes sense).

And then

```
public function validationStep2($validator)
{
    $validator = $this->validationStep1($validator)
        ->add('first_name', 'notEmpty', [
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => __('Provide your first name'),
        ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

and so on.